# accordion type menu that closes all divs except one selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do an accordion type menu without actually using the plugin. I have a jsfiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/t7mafd2a/1/

I can toggle the menu but what I want is when one is open the other close, not just have them stay open when clicked.

```js
    $('.navContainer li div').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $t = $(this);
    
        $t.next('.navtoggle').toggleClass('active', 400);
    
    });
```

```css
    .navtoggle { display: none; }
    
    .active { display: block; } .navContainer { display: block; } ul, li { list-style: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navContainer">   
     <ul>
      <li>
      <div>Category 1</div>
      <ul class="navtoggle">
        <li><a href="http//www.google.com">Test</a></li>
        <li><a href="http//www.google.com">Test</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div>Category 2</div>
      <ul class="navtoggle">
        <li><a href="http//www.google.com">Test</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div>Category 3</div>
      <ul class="navtoggle">
        <li><a href="http//www.google.com">Test</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>   
    </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add this line before you do `toggleClass`

```
$('.navtoggle').removeClass('active');
```

This will remove the `active` class from all of your `navtoggle` elements before you open the one you just clicked.

Full code:

```
$('.navContainer li div').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $t = $(this);
  var $next = $t.next('.navtoggle');
  $('.navtoggle').not($next).removeClass('active');
  $next.toggleClass('active', 400);
});
```

Comment: what about the one that is open, what if i want to close that one?

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.navContainer li div').click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault(); 
 $('ul.active').removeClass('active');
var $t = $(this);
$t.next('.navtoggle').toggleClass('active', 400);
});
```

```css
.navtoggle { display: none; }

.active { display: block; } .navContainer { display: block; } ul, li { list-style: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navContainer">   
 <ul>
  <li>
  <div>Category 1</div>
  <ul class="navtoggle">
    <li><a href="http//www.google.com">Test</a></li>
    <li><a href="http//www.google.com">Test</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div>Category 2</div>
  <ul class="navtoggle">
    <li><a href="http//www.google.com">Test</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div>Category 3</div>
  <ul class="navtoggle">
    <li><a href="http//www.google.com">Test</a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>   
</ul>
</div>
```